# Set div id dyanmically in each item in the loop to be referred in Ajax.ActionLink method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Do we have better ways to handle it?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id="divDetail@{@item.CategoryId}"/>
        @Ajax.ActionLink(
            item.CategoryName, 
            "GetDetails", 
            new { id = item.CategoryId }, 
            new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = string.Format("divDetail{0}", item.CategoryId) })
       }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the `HTML.ActionLink` helper method to generate the link and then use my custom jQuery ajax call to get the data. The advantage of doing this is i have full control so that i can do some manipulation of the response data before showing in the detail div.

I added a CSS class to the link so that i can be more specific (in selection of element) when binding my functionality.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id='divDetail@(item.ID)'></div>
    @Html.ActionLink(item.CategoryName, "GetDetails", new { @id = item.CategoryId}, new {@id= "link-"+item.CategoryId, @class="lnkItem" })    
}
```

and the script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".lnkItem").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var itemId = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]
            $.get($(this).attr("href"), { id: itemId }, function (data) {
               //i am free to do anything here before showing the data !
                $("#divDetail" + itemId).html(data);
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```